# Clock generator up to 8 MHz using pin 3 arduino nano

Tags: programming, timers

I would like to generate square signal up to 8 MHz using internal timer of arduino, I have done successfully in pin 11, but i want to change it in pin 3, but still stuck. Here is the code

```
 pinMode(11,OUTPUT);

 TCCR2A = ((1 << WGM21) | (1 << COM2A0));
 TCCR2B = (1 << CS20); // prescaler = 1
 TIMSK2 = 0;
 OCR2A = 1;
```

from this page [here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=488449.0) 
How can i change the pin to pin 3?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The MCU Timer Outputs are hardwired to specific pins. Arduino Nano (ATmega328p) pin 3 is the MCU pin PD3 and may be connected to Timer 2 output logic, OC2B with Output Compare Register 2B (OCR2B). Waveform Generator Mode and Timer Clock prescale are the same as above.

```
 pinMode(3,OUTPUT);

 TCCR2A = ((1 << WGM21) | (1 << COM2B0));
 TCCR2B = (1 << CS20); // prescaler = 1
 TIMSK2 = 0;
 OCR2B = 1;
```

Cheers!

Comment: You should also set `OCR2A`, as it defines the TOP value of the counter in CTC mode, which is the mode being used here.